# window.closeDatabase()?

Tags: cordova

In phonegap when opening a database you write window.openDatabase().
Is it possible to close the connection and if so, is it necessary?

The reason I'm asking this is because I'm opening the database every time I'm inserting a value. Mayby I have misunderstood exactly how it works connecting to a database via phonegap but in .net I always close the connection after i have inserted something.

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the reference to the DB that window.openDatabase() returns. You should be able to use it multiple times on the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean that there is no way to close it with a function?

Comment: There is no close method in the spec.